# Moving docker container to new server

Tags: docker, tar, docker-image

I have upgraded to a new server and am trying to migrate my Docker containers over.
Most of the containers that I am running are made up of multiple image files

I used the `docker commit appID appname` command to create my own images of each

and then saved all of the images to a .tar file using
`docker save image1 image2 image3 > backup.tar`

Then transfered the tar file to my new server and ran
`docker load -i backup.tar`

Which added the backup images as wel as associated volumes on to my new server...

The problem I now have is, there are 7 image files and I cannot find a way to create the docker container using these image files.

When I use the YAML file and change the image to represent the locally stored image rather than the image from the docker repository, it still pulls the image from the repository

Is there a recommended way to launch the container from the local images exported from the tar file?

Comment: The usual recommended path is to copy artifacts like the `docker-compose.yml` to the new system, and create an entirely new set of containers there.  You should almost never run `docker commit`: in the workflow you show, it will basically be impossible to take any sort of security update or other change in the underlying code.

Comment: (A Docker container is just a wrapper around a single process.  If you substitute the word "process" for "container", then you need to make sure the code [Docker image] and data [volume content] are on the target system, and then launch a new process [container] there.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have tried that, but the new images are unable to access the database volumes for some reason. This is why I tried the docker comit approach but I am getting the same issues with this

Comment: `docker commit` doesn't include volume data in the newly-created image.

Comment: @DavidMaze if it is possible to use the YAML file and copy the volumes from the old install, is there a recommended way to achieve this? I have tried copying the volumes to cloud storage and then copying them from cloud storage to the new server. But when I bring the container up, I get errors advising that the app cannot communicate with the DB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```bash
docker save -o backup.tar $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}")
```

Alternatively:

```bash
 docker save $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}") > backup.tar
```

This will tag your images with the name and tags.

Once you do

```
docker load -i backup.tar
```

and perform:

```bash
docker images -a
```

you will be able to use the images based on the `name:tag`

Comment: `docker save -o backup.tar $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}")` Can this be done...
`docker save -o backup.tar $(image1 image2 image3 image4 --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}")`
What do I put in place of repository:tag? or is that automatically assigned?

Comment: I tried using `docker save -o backup.tar $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}")` the way i mentioned in the above comment, I got the error `"docker save" requires at least 1 argument.`

Comment: @PaulMcF87 you can also try the same command `docker save $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}") > backup.tar` You need to be careful not have `<none>:<none>` type of images or else you would get an error